# Python 2.7.2 Function Syntax Error randomly occurs

Tags: python, function, syntax, python-2.7, syntax-error

I was writing a program in Python, and I keep getting a random syntax error. The only thing the error says is "`SyntaxError: invalid syntax(uppgift2.py, line 16)`"

This is the function that is a part of the program I'm working on.

```
def CalculateWordPoints(word, elementValues):
    points = 0
    # Calculate basic points and letter bonuses
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
    points += int(word[i])*ReturnLetterBonusMultiplier(elementValues[i])

    # Add word bonuses
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
        points *= ReturnWordBonusMultiplier(elementValues[i])
    return points
```

Line 16 is the first line of the function.

Comment: Look at the lines before this line.  This type of error can be caused by a missing parenthesis or the like on an earlier line.

Comment: only thing I can see without you posting some more code is that the indentation is wrong for the line starting with `points` (4 lines down from the `def`)

Comment: Thanks BrenBarn. The problem was a missing parenthesis from something previous to this function.

Also, the indentation error at line 4 was something that happened when I was copy-pasting the code from my file; it doesn't exist in my local file.

Answer (score 0):

Missed indentation here:

```
for i in range(0, len(word)):
  points += int(word[i])*ReturnLetterBonusMultiplier(elementValues[i])
```

That is not an error but it would be just more correct:

```
range(len(word))
```

And you could write these two lines more pythonic:

```
points = sum(int(w)*ReturnLetterBonusMultiplier(elementValues[i]) for (i,w) in enumerate(word))
```

And the same for the next three lines:

```
points *= product(ReturnWordBonusMultiplier(elementValues[i]) for (i,w) in enumerate(word))
```

So you could write this functions as a oneliner:

```
return sum(int(w)*ReturnLetterBonusMultiplier(elementValues[i]) for (i,w) in enumerate(word)) * product(ReturnWordBonusMultiplier(elementValues[i]) for (i,w) in enumerate(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely due to the lines before line 16.
I would guess that you opened parentheses (or something else) and forgot to close them.

Also, you have bad indentation, as Igor Chubin noted (but this would cause an error in line 20, not 16).